# Java - Trying to display last modified date for the files in a folder

Tags: java, simpledateformat, last-modified

My problem is that when I try `lastModified` function on files I get an error - `method 'lastModified' not found`. It only allows me to use the `lastModified` function on folders, and I'm unsure how to fix this. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "C:/Desktop/ExampleFolder";

    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())            
        {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy HH:mm: a");

            if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".csv") || files.endsWith(".docx")) {
                System.out.println("File Name: " + files + " , " + "Size: " + files.length() + " bytes " + " , " + "Last Modified : " + sdf.format(files.lastModified())  );
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting when using it on a file ?

Comment: method 'lastModified' not found

Comment: files is a String not a File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you wrote `files.lastModified()` where `files` is a `String`.

Don't you mean following instead ?

```
listOfFiles[i].lastModified()
```